# Trying to create low-latency audio stream with USB input to ethernet output

Tags: usb, audio, ethernet

I'm trying to route audio coming from a tv to my Sonos speaker using a [USB audio capture card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079CBGDST) (tv aux to Raspberry Pi USB input). I'm planning on using the ethernet port on the Raspi to output the audio to the Sonos ethernet port.

I have experience with Python so I'm thinking something like PyAudio to create a stream from the USB input to the ethernet output but I'm not sure if creating a stream and setting an ethernet output is possible with PyAudio. Does anyone know what tools I should be using to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

PS - I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B

Update: I found out I can use the "play_uri" function in the [Soco Python library](https://readthedocs.org/projects/soco/downloads/pdf/stable/) to write a stream to the Sonos, so I just need to initialize an audio stream using USB as the input. Does anyone know how to do this?